# Ipython installation - creating nbserver profile - missing notebook_config.py file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ipython

I am trying to use the guidance on http://www.slideshare.net/fullscreen/randyzwitch/ipython-ec2/12 to install public Ipython notebooks in an AWS instance. One problem that i encounter is, when i try to create a profile, i do **not** not observe the creation of an ipython_notebook_config_py file (as explained in the tutoral, as per the screenshot), but i only get a ipython_kernel_config.py file, which has very different contents, and cannot be edited in the way as explained in the tutoral. Can someone help me to understand why this happens, and what i should do subsequently? Many thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The notebook server is no longer part of IPython; it's a separate Jupyter project, which has its own config directory `~/.jupyter`. The config file for the notebook server is `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`. You can use this to configure the notebook server. If you want to keep multiple configurations of the notebook server, you can use the environment variable `JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR` to specify that a different directory should be used:

```
JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR=~/jupyter_nbserver jupyter notebook
```

Note: IPython has not lost its profiles or config files, so `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` and startup files, etc. continue to work as before for configuring the *IPython kernel*, just not the notebook server itself.

References:

- [Running a public notebook server](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/public_server.html)
- [Jupyter configuration](https://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html)
- [Migration from IPython to Jupyter](https://jupyter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migrating.html)